# Multi Module maven project: How to trigger all feature files across modules?

Tags: maven, ui-automation, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am writing a multi-module test automation framework where i have a **parent project** known as framework and **2 child modules/projects** - core and customer. **customer module is dependent on core module**

[image]

I am using cucumber-junit to write feature files. Both core and customer modules will have feature files and step definitions. Following dependencies are added in core project:

[image]

I have created a TestRunner.java file in core module as shown below:

[image]

When i run TestRunner.java as a JUnit test, it only executes the feature file in core module. **The feature file in customer module do not execute**.

Is there a way to execute all the feature files in all child projects / modules?

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parent pom.xml in the framework project and within it declare the two child modules. Then execute the maven command like "clean install" on this parent pom.

```
Framework pom...
    <groupId>multi.mod</groupId>
    <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>customer</module>
    </modules>

    You can add common dependencies and refer to them in the child modules by the 
    artifact id mentioned in the parent pom.
```

---

```
Core pom...
   <parent>
        <groupId>multi.mod</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

   Add dependencies as required
```

---

```
Customer pom...
   <parent>
        <groupId>multi.mod</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>customer</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

  Add dependencies as required plus add core module also as dependency
       <dependency>
            <groupId>multi.mod</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Run clean install on the parent pom ie. framework**

https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: You only have to use the 'Framework pom...'. This is called aggregation/aggretor-pom, which will call all it specified modules.